# Cannot write to External Storage on Android 11

Tags: java, android

Except for MainActivity, I have Something class to do some stuff and IOStream class to do the write/read external files. However, FileOutputStream does not work when I call from Something class, even though it works when I calls it from MainActivity.

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.spr.rw;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Something someting = new Something(this);
    }
}
```

This is my Something (I will use this later on for Firebase functions)

```
package com.spr.rw;

import android.content.Context;

public class Something {
    public Something(Context context){
        IOStream writeTool = new IOStream(context, "20220531");
        writeTool.writeToFile("placeholder");
    }
}
```

This is my IOStream

```
package com.spr.rw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class IOStream {
    private Context context;
    int today;

    private File file;
    private File location;

    public IOStream(Context context, String today) {
        this.context = context;
        File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        this.file = new File(folder, "spr-backup-" + today + ".txt");
    }

    // Writing data
    public void writeToFile(String data) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Reading data
    private String readFromFile(Context context) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

My manifest, which I have put in the permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.spr.rw">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RW"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the error logs. No file is created but it says File exists?

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/spr-backup-20220531.txt: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
W/System.err:     at com.spr.rw.IOStream.writeToFile(IOStream.java:27)
W/System.err:     at com.spr.rw.Something.<init>(Something.java:8)
W/System.err:     at com.spr.rw.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8373)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
W/System.err:   ... 19 more
```

I tried many ways, but it still has this same bug.

---

I tried to check if file exists when IOStream is created, but it still face the same bug.

```
public IOStream(Context context, String today) {
    this.context = context;
    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    this.file = new File(folder, "spr-backup-" + today + ".txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I read on Stackoverflow about Android 11 permission, so I add extra permission in Manifest, but it does not work either.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You are not closing the stream. I dont see you using exists(). I dont see code for onCreate().

Comment: I close the stream on IOStream class when the writing is finished.  There is onCreate() on MainActivity? And if I put file.exists() in, the problem will be the same. Normally, if I call IOStream from MainActivity, it will work, but when I try to call it in Something, it stops working.

Comment: You have no Toast in catch block to inform the user.

Comment: Why do I need Toast? I am trying to write to external storage.

Comment: You cannot overwrite or delete a file created in `Documents` by another app directly using the filesystem.

Comment: There is no file in Documents when I run the app. Also, if I call IOStream from MainActivity, I can still read/write/create/delete file. It just refuses to work when I call from Something class.